# Get parameters via ajax? (sync, async)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

i have the next problem:

I have the next AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
     data: parametros,
     url: 'attack.php',
     type: 'get',
     beforeSend: function() {
        $("#attack").html("Wait please...");
     },
     success: function(response) {
     //Response saying succes attack                   
     $("#attack").html(response);                                    
        score = //returned score via AJAX;                           
     }
     });
```

And the PHP:

```
    //Some BD connections and querys

if ($win == true) {
   //The message
   echo "You won the battle!";
   //The value that must be returned
   $score = $score + 10;
}else {
   //The message
   echo "You been defeted in battle!";
   //The value that must be returned
   $score = $score + -10;
}
```

I need to get some returned value from my attack.php to put it inside my var score.
but i can't find the way, i saw some posts that say to do it syncronous beside of asyncronous but i don't get it...

Hope anyone can post an example of how to get returned parameters from my PHP, Thanks!

Comment: What's the response from `attack.php`?  That response would be in the `response` variable.  It *should* just be a JSON-serialized value or set of values.  `score` can then be set to any value therein.

Comment: Sorry i forgot it, i'll do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `json_encode` your response from the server and then access multiple variables from it.

## php

```
$data = array();
if ($win == true) {
   //The message
   $data['msg'] = "You won the battle!";
   //The value that must be returned
   $data['score'] = $score + 10;
}else {
   //The message
   $data['msg'] = "You been defeted in battle!";
   //The value that must be returned
   $data['score'] = $score -10;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

## jQuery

```
$.ajax({
     data: parametros,
     url: 'attack.php',
     type: 'get',
     dataType: 'json', // telling the function to expect json response
     beforeSend: function() {
        $("#attack").html("Wait please...");
     },
     success: function(response) {
     // accessing array variables via keys                
     $("#attack").html(response.msg);                                    
        score = response.score;                
     }
});
```

Note: Make sure nothing else is returned/echoed from the php page (notices/warnings/etc) apart from the `$data` array else you'll get JSON error on the client side.

Comment: I got something like that = {"msg":"You won the battle!"} Why? How i can get only the string "You won the battle!"? Thanks again!

Comment: `response.msg` will get you only the string

Comment: I have the same code as you post, and i got {"msg":"You won the battle!"}, maybe i need to do something with the $data ?

Comment: With Chrome console debuging i see that: RESPONSE: {"msg":"You won the battle!"}

Comment: Could you show me your `success: function` code?

Comment: Ohhh!!! i got it! The problem was      dataType: 'json', // telling the function to expect json response

The comentary... wow thanks a bilion times to answer me that fast!